# update 2nd row in 1st row in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wanted to update contact in the same row.
Both rows have the same email account, first row has no contact, second row has contact.
How do I update the contact in first row.

[image]

Updated problem
I used the suggested solution. But when there is not all the account has 2 rows. It will get the wrong contact. Just like ccc@gmail.com
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Excel, how do you auto fill until next value?](https://superuser.com/questions/603318/in-excel-how-do-you-auto-fill-until-next-value)

Comment: So the ccc@gmail.com's contact is " "(empty)?

Comment: @MátéJuhász similar, but my one is more complicated.

Comment: Can you post some editable example?

Comment: If everything is like that, use Power Query; select the Contact column, and `Fill Up`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- select column D
- hit F5 or Ctrl+G to open the Go To dialog
- Click **Special**
- Tick **Blanks** and hit OK. Now all blank cells are selected.
- without changing the selection, type a `=` character and hit the **down arrow** key. That will enter a formula that refers to the cell below.
- hold down the Ctrl key and hit Enter. Now all selected cells contain a formula that refers to the cell below.
- Select and copy column D, then paste as values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you take a look for my question. I have added 2 images. @teylyn. When not all the accounts have 2 rows. It will get the wrong contact.

Comment: Sort your data so the filled cell comes first and the rows with the blank cell comes after that. Then use my approach, but use the UP arrow instead the DOWN arrow. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another column with the formula below. Drag it down to fill the other cells.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK($D2),$C2=$C3),$D3,$D2)
```

Note that if a contact number is blank, it will appear as a `0`.

[image: Formula results]