# Excel shortcut equivalent of double clicking fill handle (not ctrl + D)

Tags: microsoft-excel, hotkeys, auto-form-fill, handle

is there a shortcut equivalent of double clicking the fill handle for Excel? I am aware of ctrl + D and that is not the functionality I need.

With ctrl + D it's necessary to manually select the cells you want to fill. I am searching for shortcut that is the same as double clicking fill handle, it automatically fills down to any cells with data in the adjacent cell and it is not necessary to select the cells in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, also see https://superuser.com/questions/298276/excel-keyboard-shortcut-to-copy-fill-down-for-all-cells-with-non-blank-adjacent