# Is there a way to autofill cells in Excel 2013 with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office-2013

So very shortly, I want a shortcut equivalent to dragging the little handle in the right-bottom in a cell-selection portion in Excel 2013 (for Windows).

There is many similar questions on the site, but either the questions or their answers are non-relevant for me and my needs, so I am going to give you specific details here of what I want to do and my constraints.

- I want a keyboard SHORTcut (the answer "ALT+H+F+I+S+ENTER" is superfluous since it is a menu-mnemonic path and not a shortcut)
- I want to AUTO-fill (the fill-down/right shortcuts "CTRL+D" and "CTRL+R" are not relevant since it just copies values. I am searching something like this, but the action being "autofill", not "fill")
- I don't want to duplicate formulas, don't propose to make formulas instead of using absolute values, I want to auto fill series (numbers/dates etc...)

Since I didn't find anything during my research I suspect there is no way of doing so, but are there any way to solve this with "custom-shortcuts" or macros (which I have no experience of)?

Comment: Actually, the fill down/right/up/left commands also copy formatting. (I know that from experience using them.) If what you're copying refers to other cells, the new cell will contain references to cells below/to the right/above/to the left of the originally referenced cells the same distance away as the destination cell of the fill is from the source cell.

Comment: https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=excel+fill+down+VBA - brings up hits that might help get on the way with VBA/Macros - but I doubt that you will be able to achieve something similar to the use of the fill handle.

Comment: [Fill a large range with a formula in Excel, without mouse-dragging to extend](https://superuser.com/q/948175/241386), [Possible to apply a function to an entire column?](https://superuser.com/q/947185/241386), [Apply Formula to a Range of Cells without Drag and Drop](https://superuser.com/q/180345/241386), [How to make Excel 2010 auto-fill new row with formulas?](https://superuser.com/q/554685/241386), [Excel Auto-Fill a Series Without Mouse](https://superuser.com/q/270018/241386), [AutoFill Large Number of Cells in Excel?](https://superuser.com/q/364276/241386)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the *Quick Access Toolbar* or QAT.

[image: QAT More Commands]

Use the pull-down on the QAT (shown above) and choose *More Commands*. When you get to Excel Options ► Quick Access Toolbar you can pick `Fill Series` from the *Home Tab* group and add it to the QAT.

Use the positioning arrow buttons to set the commands position before committing the command addition with `OK`. This is important as its position will also set the keyboard shortcut. The first is `Alt+1`, the second is `Alt+2`, etc.

[image: QAT Alt keys]

With that in place, you just have to tap `Alt+<whatever>` to get your Home ► Editing ► Fill ► Series command. It looks like you might need to hit `Enter` to accept the *Series* dialog's suggested method of `AutoFill`, but that is simply because there are usually choices.

FWIW, my own command demon has always been Home ► Clipboard ► Paste ► Paste Special ► Values. I have set the `Paste Values` in my QAT at position 2. Now I can simply `Ctrl+C` then `Alt+2` to copy and paste special, values. I also usually remove `Save`, `Undo` and `Redo` to make room for other custom QAT commands as I can remember `Ctrl+S`, `Ctrl+Z` and `Ctrl+Y`.

More on the QAT at: [Customize the Quick Access Toolbar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-HA010362102.aspx)

On a related note, double-clicking the *Fill Handle* of a cell with a formula is the equivalent of `Fill Down` according the the number of populated cells to the left. I habitually use `Ctrl+D` but if my hand is already on the mouse, this is an alternative. Experiment with this little-known/used trick and you might want to add it to your repertoire.

Comment: This is actually a solution I haven't thought about or seen before that I will consider, though I will wait to mark this as the answer to my question since it feels like there should be a smiple/obvious keyboard shortcut equivalent to dragging the bottom-right handle in a cell-selection.

Comment: Nice explanation +1

Comment: I forgot to update, but this was an excellent neat solution that I now use, thanks!