# Excel 2010 - possible to apply a function to an entire column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In Excel 2010, is it possible to apply a function (not a formula) to an entire column (without dragging the plus symbol all the way to the bottom)?

Comment: What *specifically* are you wanting to do?

Answer (score 2):

A function is part of a formula. So the below should work in exactly the same way.

Select the column you want:

[image: Select Column]

Paste your formula:

[image]

Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Done!